# Difference between numbers.Real and float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

I happen to have a look at the source code of a python library `diffprivlib`. They defined a function as follows:

```
from numbers import Real

def set_epsilon_1(epsilon):
    if not isinstance(epsilon, Real):
        raise TypeError("epsilon must be numeric")
    else: 
        return float(epsilon)
```

My question is, if the purpose is to return number as float, why not check it against float like below.

```
def set_epsilon_2(epsilon):
    if not isinstance(epsilon, float):
        raise TypeError("epsilon must be numeric")
    else: 
        return float(epsilon)
```

What is the difference between float and Real?

Comment: `Reals` is an abstract base class that specifies an interface that anything representing a real number type should be able to handle. You can use it to e.g. define your own implementation

Comment: Consider that your implementation would reject `1`, even though `1` is a numeric value.

Comment: my big problem is that I already set `self.epsilon: Union[Real, None] = None` in one of my class. When I try to set the returned value from function, `mypy` shows type errors. is there any way to overcome this?